# IntelliJ: can't execute SVN through batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, intellij-idea

When using SVN from IntelliJ I wrapped my SVN client in a batch file in order to do some processing with it. Actually the batch file will call a [Powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) script. It works fine when I invoke it from the command line, yet when I configure IntelliJ to use that batch file as the SVN command line client I get the following error:

> Can't use Subversion command line client: mySvn.bat
>
> Probably the path to Subversion executable is wrong. Fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE calls a batch file that calls PowerShell script... Why using several wrappers in a row instead of just a single one around regular command-line client?

IDE verifies executable by trying to execute it and making sure the call does not fail with a timeout and does not return errors. Looks like one of the wrappers returns an error code.

It works fine for me if I wrap svn calls into e.g. a bat file, or sh script on Mac.

Comment: It works if I wrap the svn call into a .bat file. But I need to do some additional processing with Powershell, that's why I have to call the Powershell script. Would it be possible to call the Powershell script from IntelliJ?

Comment: Since PowerShell is not the default OS shell, IntelliJ won't be able to use that. If PowerShell is set as default via the registry, then it will probably work. However, it appears to work for me even with the double wrapper. Just make sure your wrapper does not output anything different than svn itself. In the simple test case, I just set `@echo off` to make it work.

Comment: ```@echo off
Powershell.exe -File "C:\Users\dsmirnov\Desktop\svn.ps1" %*``` that's it. svn.ps1 wraps svn command line.